# Reassigning Column Values within Variable Groups

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this particular dataframe and would like to conduct some manipulation on this. Basically, I want to stagger the values such that each entry in the salary column moves up to replace the earlier season's salary.

How do i do it? via iloc or? If there is no previous season entry, I would want to leave it untouched (see row 3).

Input Dataframe:

```
   season                       url  salary
1 2016-17 /players/a/abrinal01.html 5994764
2 2017-18 /players/a/abrinal01.html 5725000
3 2008-09 /players/a/ackeral01.html  711517
4 2012-13   /players/a/acyqu01.html  665000
5 2013-14   /players/a/acyqu01.html  788872
6 2014-15   /players/a/acyqu01.html  915243
```

Output Dataframe:

```
   season                       url  salary
1 2016-17 /players/a/abrinal01.html 5725000
2 2017-18 /players/a/abrinal01.html    NA
3 2008-09 /players/a/ackeral01.html  711517
4 2012-13   /players/a/acyqu01.html  788872
5 2013-14   /players/a/acyqu01.html  915243
6 2014-15   /players/a/acyqu01.html    NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lead` from `dplyr` assuming `season` is ordered as shown in example

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(url) %>%
  mutate(salary = if (n() > 1) lead(salary) else salary)

#   season  url                        salary
#  <fct>   <fct>                       <int>
#1 2016-17 /players/a/abrinal01.html 5725000
#2 2017-18 /players/a/abrinal01.html      NA
#3 2008-09 /players/a/ackeral01.html  711517
#4 2012-13 /players/a/acyqu01.html    788872
#5 2013-14 /players/a/acyqu01.html    915243
#6 2014-15 /players/a/acyqu01.html        NA
```